# check which item is selected?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I try to check which data is selected in a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`

```
Dim status As Double
    For x As Integer = 0 To ATCGRID.Rows.Count - 1
        If ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = "Full" Then
            status = 1
        ElseIf ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = "Empty" Then
            status = 0
        ElseIf ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = "Half" Then
            status = 0.5
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(status)
    Next x
```

But Its getting error

```
Conversion from string "Full" to type "Double" is not valid.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: try add `.ToString()` → `MessageBox.Show(status.ToString())`, or use the `.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()` → `ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == "Full"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Parse your type database,

```
    Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE(EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_DATE,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK)VALUES(@EMP_ID,@EMP_NAME,@AT_DATE,@AT_STATUS,@AT_REMARK)"
        query = New SqlCommand(strSQL, Conn)
        query.Parameters.Add("@EMP_ID",SqlDbType.Decimal)
        query.Parameters.Add("@EMP_ID").Value=id
        query.Parameters.Add("@EMP_NAME",SqlDbType.Varchar,100)' Parse your length 
        query.Parameters.Add("@EMP_NAME").Value=name
        query.Parameters.Add("@AT_DATE",SqlDbType.Date)
        query.Parameters.Add("@AT_DATE").Value=atdate
        query.Parameters.Add("@AT_STATUS",SqlDbType.Decimal)
        query.Parameters.Add("@AT_STATUS").Value=status
        query.Parameters.Add("@AT_REMARK",SqlDbType.Varchar,50)
        query.Parameters.Add("@AT_REMARK").Value=name
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` in the cells is a number, so it cannot be compared that way. Try this:

```
If ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString() = "FULL" Then
```